# position absolute div broken

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container_1">A</div>
    <div class="container_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam consequat diam non neque imperdiet cursus ut ut erat. Sed pellentesque congue justo, sed auctor velit posuere ac.></div>    
</div>
```

And my css is like this:

```
.main div
{
    float:left;
}

.main .container_2
{
    width:500px;
}

.main .container_1
{
    width:40px;
}

.main
{
    position:absolute;      
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#365;
}
```

The problem I have is, when I don't use `position:absolute;` on my `main` div, everything is broken (you can view the example on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SNnM/5/). Everything works fine only if I use position absolute on the main div, but I don't wanna use position absolute because I want the main div to preseve its space in the document. Any help please?

Thank you

Comment: Is not using `float :left` for the child divs, an option?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `clear` whenever you have floating elements to make sure the parent wraps all their content, I like to use CSS `:after` for this

```
.main:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either float the main div or give it `display:inline-block` to take the complete dimension of its floating children, unless you want to add `<div style="clear:both;float:none;"></div>` in the markup just before the closing of container div and after the last floating element.

```
.main
{

    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#365;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YAvpS/)**

**[All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `.main` div have `overflow: auto` to take on the height of its floating child.

```
.main
{
    overflow: auto;      
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#365;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the children of `main` are floating you have to add `overflow: hidden` in the `main` or add another `div` as:

```
    <div style="clear: both;float:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
overflow:auto
```

instead of

```
position:absolute;
```

on .main

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SNnM/7/)

Comment: then there's that ugly scroll bar

Comment: hmm i dont see a scroll bar in FF

Comment: Its fine, I had to adjust the output window width

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your container is not floated and so due to the weirdness of floats does not fully contain the interior items that are floating.

adding:

```
.main{
    float: left;
}
```

fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid absolute positioning at all costs.  If I find myself absolutely positioning something just to get it to display the "correct" way I usually look elsewhere for issues.

For me, absolute positioning is saved for when I want to make elements sticky, like a top nav, or bottom footer, or something along those lines.

Like most have said here.  Float the main div.  Should help alleviate some headaches.

I cleaned some stuff up here, and updated: http://jsfiddle.net/s58TF/

```
.main_2{
padding:5px;
color:#fff;
background-color:#365;
float:left;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

--  Or --

The clearfix method (if you don't want to use "overflow: hidden" for other reasons): http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

This one works, usually:

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Just add the class "group" to the "main" div, or replace "group" with "main."  Here's the clearfix method applied and working: http://jsfiddle.net/ksyFG/

---

To be clear, these are two separate solutions: "overflow: hidden" or clearfix.

Comment: Koala_dev and Jonathan Naguin had the same/similar solutions below.